# Bootstrap 4 layout with one width fixed column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is my html code:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex h-100">
  <div class="white h-100" style="background-color: white;">
    fixed 100px
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 blue h-100" style="background-color: blue;">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 red h-100" style="background-color: red;">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 blue h-100" style="background-color: blue;">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me to fix my code please? I need on left side column with fixed width, which will be have 100px. This column have not resize. Rest of space I need to should be dynamically adjustable in ratio 1 : 2 : 1. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

@Denis Stephanov, you can create a flex item that doesn't shrink or grow and has a fixed width, with the following css rule:

```
.flex-fixed-width-item {
    flex: 0 0 100px;
}
```

This is the short-hand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`. You can read more about these properties in this [CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/).

Adding that class to your fixed width column:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex h-100">
  <div class="white h-100 flex-fixed-width-item" style=" background-color: white;">
    fixed 100px
  </div>
  ...
```

Then keeping your column ratio the same:

```
  ...
  <div class="col-2 blue h-100" style="background-color: blue;">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="col-4 red h-100" style="background-color: red;">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 blue h-100" style="background-color: blue;">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll get your requested outcome, which you can view in this [codeply project](https://www.codeply.com/go/unHU8v14t4).

Comment: No, in fact. I just took out the columns, and turned the `div` tags into flex items. Take a look at [it now](https://www.codeply.com/go/unHU8v14t4).

Answer (score 35):

There is a built-in solution in bootstrap 4.

Try this;

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md">
            content
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-auto">
            <div style="background: red; width: 300px;">
                sidebar
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.bootply.com/WiegnnJbxX

Answer (score 19):

Bootstrap 4 has this built into their layout components.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <!-- Set Width Column -->
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <!-- Variable Width Column -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width

If you would like your set width column to have a fixed pixel width, you can omit `.col-4` and add a custom pixel width class.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-pixel-width-100">
      <!-- Set Width Column -->
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <!-- Variable Width Column -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

// style.css
.col-pixel-width-100 { flex: 0 0 100px; }
```

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers solved the problem I faced.
And I have come up with such a solution:
(it is not effective but it works.)

```css
.my-fixed-col{
  width: 150px;
}

.my-fluid-col{
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
}

/***/
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container-fluid d-flex p-0 m-0">
  <div class="row p-0 m-0 w-100">
    
    <div class="my-fixed-col bg-primary text-white p-1">
        150px fixed column
    </div>
    
    <div class="my-fluid-col bg-danger text-white p-1">
        fluid column
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```